# How to load dynamic table to Razor Page using ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core-2.1

I am building one Report page for all reports based on `@RouteData.Values`. My all reports comes from `HomeController` and I just want to display them to a `#table1` in Razor Page.

Reports are dynamic size in row and coloumn.

Reports RazorPageView

```
@page "{id}"
@model Test.Pages.Reports.IndexModel

<table id="table1" class="table table-responsive">        
</table>

@section Scripts {
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
        var id = @RouteData.Values["id"];        
        switch (id) {
            case 'Customers':
                apipath = 'GetAllCustomers';
                break;
            case 'Vendors':
                apipath = 'GetAllVendors';
                break;
            default:
                apipath = 'SomeOtherReport';
        }
        $.ajax({            
                url: "/Home/" + apipath,                
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                datatype: JSON,
                success: function (result) {
                    //Here i want to load dynamic type table data to #table1
                }
        });
    });
  </script>
}
```

Home Controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller  
   {  
       [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult GetAllCustomers()
        {
            var result = _Context.Customers.ToList();
            return Json(result);
        }

    [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult GetAllVendors()
        {
            var result = _Context.Vendors.ToList();
            return Json(result);
        } 
   }
```

so that my url looks "~/Reports/Customers" or "~/Reports/Vendors"

Comment: exactly what u will get in `result` in `success` function of `ajax`

Comment: List of Customers/Vendors data. Coloumn types and names are dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below to your success callback.

```
var allProperties = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(result[0]);
var tableHeader ='<tr>';
for(var i=0; i<allProperties.length; i++)
    {
        tableHeader += '<th>'+allProperties[i]+'</th>'
    }

var allRows = tableHeader + '</tr>';
for(var index =0;index<result.length; index++)
{
    var row = '<tr>';
    for(var i=0; i<allProperties.length; i++)
    {
        row += '<td>'+result[index][allProperties[i]]+'</td>'
    }
    row += '</tr>';
allRows  += row;
}
$('#table1').append(allRows);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Try Following**

if following is your `ajax` `success` function
and suppose in the `result` ur getting **columns (id,name,address)**

```
success: function (result) {
   var reportBody='';  
   $('#table1').empty();//clear table body               
   if(result.d.length>0)
   {
   //create body using $.each
   $.each(result.d,function(i,info){
   reportBody+='<tr><td>'+info.id+'</td><td>'+info.name+'</td><td>'+info.address+'</td></tr>'  
   });
   }
   else
   {
   reportBody+='<tr><td>There is no Record</td></tr>'
   }
   //append body to table table1 as follow
   $('#table1').append('<thead><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Address</th></tr></theah><tbody>'+reportBody+'</tbody>');
                }
```

Comment: Coloumn names are unknown as of now because Customer will have different coloumn names comparative to Vendor